# Decide if an edge cross some min-cut in flow network

Tags: algorithm, graph, proof

Let G=(V,E) be a flow network. Let e=(u,v) be an edge in E and let f be a maximum flow in G. Prove or Disprove:

Proof\disproof:

'If the residual graph Gf contains no directed path from u to v then e crosses some minimum cut in G.'

I haven't been able to find an example which condratics it nor to prove it

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford–Fulkerson_algorithm#Integral_example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford–Fulkerson_algorithm#Integral_example)

Comment: which edge ? doesnt seem to work.

Comment: It really depends on what your definition of "minimum cut" is. In the context of a maximum flow problem, a minimum cut is [a set of edges, which if removed, disconnect the sink from the source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem). By that definition, the edge from B to C disproves the statement.